# correct GeoJSON format. map visualization

Tags: dictionary, visualization, geojson, topojson

First things first: is [this data](https://github.com/smenglish/curly-chainsaw) in proper GeoJSON format?

---

According to the [definition of GeoJSON data](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#examples), as you can see by the `MultiPoint` & `coordinates`, I think it is.

It looks like this:

```
{
    "lang": {
        "code": "en", 
        "conf": 1.0
    }, 
    "group": "JobServe", 
    "description": "Work with the data science team to build new products and integrate analytics\ninto existing workflows. Leverage big data solutions, advanced statistical\nmethods, and web apps. Coordinate with domain experts, IT operations, and\ndevelopers. Present to clients.\n\n  * Coordinate the workflow of the data science team\n  * Join a team of experts in big data, advanced analytics, and visualizat...", 
    "title": "Data Science Team Lead", 
    "url": "http://www.jobserve.com/us/en/search-jobs-in-Columbia,-Maryland,-USA/DATA-SCIENCE-TEAM-LEAD-99739A4618F8894B/", 
    "geo": {
        "type": "MultiPoint", 
        "coordinates": [
            [
                -76.8582049, 
                39.2156213
            ]
        ]
    }, 
    "tags": [
        "Job Board"
    ], 
    "spider": "jobserveNa", 
    "employmentType": [
        "Unspecified"
    ], 
    "lastSeen": "2015-05-13T01:21:07.240000", 
    "jobLocation": [
        "Columbia, Maryland, United States of America"
    ], 
    "identifier": "99739A4618F8894B", 
    "hiringOrganization": [
        "Customer Relation Market Research Company"
    ], 
    "firstSeen": "2015-05-13T01:21:07+00:00"
},
```

I want to visualize this as a "zoomable",viz. interactive, map, as in the examples on the [d3js website](http://d3js.org/).

I'm trying to use a tool called [mapshaper.org](http://www.mapshaper.org/) to see an initial visualization of the data in map form, but when I load it up, nothing happens.

To me this doesn't make sense because, according to their website, one can simply

```
Drag and drop or select a file to import. 
Shapefile, GeoJSON and TopoJSON files and Zip archives are supported.
```

However, in my case it is not working.

Does anyone have any intuition as to what might be going wrong, or a suggestion as to a tool comparable to create a zoomable map out of GeoJSON data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to the definition of GeoJSON data, I have what I think constitutes data in that format

Well, you don't have a proper GeoJSON object. Just compare what you've got against the example you've linked. It doesn't even come close. That's why mapshaper doesn't know what to do with the JSON you load into it.

> A GeoJSON object with the type "FeatureCollection" is a feature collection object. An object of type "FeatureCollection" must have a member with the name "features". The value corresponding to "features" is an array. Each element in the array is a feature object as defined above.

A feature collection looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        // Array of features
    ]
}
```

http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-collection-objects

> A GeoJSON object with the type "Feature" is a feature object. A feature object must have a member with the name "geometry". The value of the geometry member is a geometry object as defined above or a JSON null value. A feature object must have a member with the name "properties". The value of the properties member is an object (any JSON object or a JSON null value). If a feature has a commonly used identifier, that identifier should be included as a member of the feature object with the name "id".

A feature looks like this:

```
{
     "id": "Foo",
     "type": "Feature",
     "geometry": {
         "type": "Point",
         "coordinates": [0, 0]
     },
     "properties": {
          "label": "My Foo"
     }
 }
```

http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-objects

Here are examples of the different geometry objects a feature can support: http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#appendix-a-geometry-examples

Put those two together, it would look like this:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "id": "Foo",
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [0, 0]
        },
        "properties": {
            "label": "My Foo"
        }
    },{
        "id": "Bar",
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
                [100.0, 0.0],
                [101.0, 1.0]
            ]
        },
        "properties": {
            "label": "My Bar"
        }
    }]
}
```

That really doesn't look like the JSON you've posted. You'll need to convert that to proper GeoJSON somehow via a custom script or manually. It's a format i've never seen before, sorry to say.